# Google Bigquery data import from Google Analytics 360

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I've read at the link "[Set up BigQuery Export](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en)" that the import process from GA 360 happens 3 times every day:

> "3 files will be exported each day that contain the current day's
>   data"

Is there a way to make this load happen every hour or a in a shorten period of time?

Comment: Hi! , the batch process it's handle by Google, the intraday table it's updated 3 -5 time (at least what i saw), but the update behaviour is a little weird, sometimes is delayed other days are slightly more fast , and sometime no  intraday table is available during a brief period.    
Tere is not so much more information, but you can take a look on:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=es

Comment: Hi Kemen, thanks for the support!